# jQuery .css() won't change element background color

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I've replaced my mouse pointer with a css element (".cursory"). Now it's a little green circle. I've put up a timer that detects when the mouse is idle for 2 seconds. I want to change the green color to red when the mouse is idle, but I can't figure out how to get ("cursory").css(...) to work. Below is my code, the problem .css() is in the goInactive function:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script><!--this is the jQuery document link-->

<script>
// this is where jQuery functions go

//TESTING IF THE UI IS IDLE
    var TimeoutID;

    function inputdetect() {
        // attaches event handler to specified event
        // takes event as string, function to run, and optional boolean
        // to indicate when the event propogates
        // these are false, so events "bubble up"
        this.addEventListener("mousemove",resetTimer,false);
        this.addEventListener("mousedown",resetTimer,false);
        this.addEventListener("mousewheel",resetTimer,false);
        this.addEventListener("keypress",resetTimer,false);
        this.addEventListener("touchmove",resetTimer,false);
        this.addEventListener("DOMmousescroll",resetTimer,false);
        this.addEventListener("MSpointermove",resetTimer,false);

        startTimer();
    }

    inputdetect();

    function startTimer() {
        //waits two seconds before calling inactive
        TimeoutID = window.setTimeout(goInactive,2000); // does it need to take the window variable??

    }

    function resetTimer(e) {
        window.clearTimeout(TimeoutID);
        goActive();

    }

    function goActive() {

        //what happens when the UI is not idle

        $('p').text("The UI is not idle.");
        startTimer();
    }

    function goInactive() {

        $('p').text("The UI is idle.");
        // REPLACING CURSOR WHEN UI IS IDLE
        //this part won't work
        $('cursory').css("background-color","red");


    }

// THIS changes the pointer to a css element
 $(document).ready(function() { 

      $(document).on('mousemove', function(e) {
            $('.cursory').css({
                left: e.pageX,
                top: e.pageY
            });
        });

});

</script>

</head>
<style>
/*this is where CSS styling goes*/

    html {
      cursor: none;

    }
    .cursory {

      height: 10px;
      width: 10px;
      border-radius: 100%;
      background-color: green;
      position: relative;

    }


</style>

<body>
<div class = "cursory"></div>
<!--this is where the HTML will go*/-->
<p>hello</p>
```

Comment: you miss . from  $('cursory').css("background-color","red"); it should $('.cursory') because class is selected with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`cursory` is the class of the element, use class selector `.className`

```
$('.cursory').css("background-color","red");
```

Comment: @mplungjan, agreed, seems like a typo. I was unable to click on community wiki at start. But I preferred an answer over comment because 1. Comments of go unnoticed over answer. 2. You can see tons of similar answers loading below now.

Answer (score -1):

Propably the problem is missing "." ...

```
$('.cursory').css("background-color","red");
```

A little article about selectors for you:
http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp

Answer (score -1):

Based on the code you have above, it looks like your not using the appropriate CSS selector in your jQuery call.

Change this

```
$('cursory').css("background-color","red");
```

to

```
$('.cursory').css("background-color","red");
```